# Intent filter for android downloads

Tags: java, android

I have made a download manager for android, my problem is that I don't know which intent to use to fire up my download manager instead of the default manager of android to download from the browser. can you help ?

Answer (score 0):

We normally use below intent to trigger download

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(httpPathToFile));
```

here if `httpPathToFile` is a `http` `url`, Browser start downloading it. You can listen for Action View here, and if it is URL you can take care of it accordingly.

Comment: I have registered this as intent filter but it doesn't trigger any calls to Intent.ACTION_VIEW